# Tomcat and java memory leak

Tags: java, hibernate, memory-leaks, tomcat7

I've developed a java web application that is currently deployed in tomcat7 on debian(raspberry py).
When the application starts the used memory is like 20%. But when i call my  own webserver it calls a rest api it returns more than 1k entities(JSON-> Java objects) and iterate over them to save using hibernate.
To populate the database i need to call this many many times and after 5 ou 6 calls the memory usage reach almost the max value and never get better. Also i can see that after a couple of calls the speed of download and save(batch) gets so so so slower.

What i'm doing wrong? it is possibe that all the entities are not being deleted after usage?

This is a image about [Memory Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSGiv.png)

Regards

Comment: Please, add your saving method.

Comment: Possibly a leak. But you will have to add code for us to verify this.

Comment: Use a profiler to see how your application us using memory. It might be a leak, it might be that your application just needs more memory than is available.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the problem. When using hibernate i was opening a new connection for every object that i needed to save. But i missed the close statement.